# Decrementing an index in multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

In order to process data in an array using multithreading, I'd like to access each element of the array using an index. Each thread decrements the index and uses its current value to process the corresponding data in the array. The index is an atomic integer and decremented until it's -1 (or 0xFF). How can I prevent the value of the index to become less than -1?

```
data_type myData[MAX_DATA_COUNT];
std::atomic<uint16_t> data_index;

void process_array()
{
    uint16_t index = data_index.fetch_sub(1); // problem starts here!
    //
    if(index != -1)
    { 
      do_something_with(myData[index]); // process data at index
    }
    else
    {
        data_index = -1;
    }
}

void worker_thread()
{
   while(is_running){
      wait_for_data();
      process_array();
   }
}
```

The problem is that multiple threads can subtract 1 from `data_index` and make it less than -1. How can I do this?

Comment: One option is to protect the counter with a `std::mutex` instead. Then, each thread can lock the mutex, check the current counter value, decide whether to decrement it, then unlock the mutex.

Comment: *"like to access each element of the array using an index."* - I suggest you give each thread a range of indices to process instead.  The normal way to do it is to provide a start (and often end) value as argument(s) to the thread startup function.

Comment: Either you use a mutex or you restructure your code to live with the fact that the index can get below -1. If it's some kind of flag that processing has been terminated, just change the check so that it checks if it's less than zero in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [compare_exchange](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange) method. This is a standard way for modify variable only after successfull check.

```
void process_array()
{
    uint16_t index = data_index.load();

    while((index != -1) && !data_index.compare_exchange_weak(index, index - 1));

    if(index != -1)
    { 
      do_something_with(myData[index]); // process data at index
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! I was thinking I should do something with `compare_exchange` myself, but couldn't figure out how to use it. Thanks!